# How can i stop the connection from getting closed while reading data from Oracle DB using Spring Batch?

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, database-connection, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch with Spring boot Application in which I am reading data from external Oracle DB and Writing it to SQL Server in production environment. I am validating the connection before reading the data but even then getting Closed Connection issue.Is anyone aware of this issue ? Below is the Datasource config code and error logs.

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class DataSourceReaderConfig {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataSourceReaderConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "oracle.datasource")
    @Bean(name="dataSourceReader")
    @Primary
    public  DataSource dataSourceReader() {
        LOGGER.info("Inside dataSourceReader Method");
        DataSource datasource = new DataSource();
        OracleDataSource ocpds = null;
        try {
            ocpds = new OracleDataSource();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            LOGGER.error("Error getting Oracle Datasource Connection = " + e1.getMessage());
        }
        ocpds.setURL(env.getProperty("oracle.datasource.url"));
        ocpds.setUser(env.getProperty("oracle.datasource.username"));
        ocpds.setPassword(env.getProperty("oracle.datasource.password"));

        try {
            ocpds.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
        } catch (SQLException e2) {
            LOGGER.error("Error Setting OracleDataSource ImplicitCachingEnabled = " + e2.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            ocpds.setConnectionCachingEnabled(true);
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            LOGGER.error("Error Setting OracleDataSource ConnectionCachingEnabled = " + e1.getMessage());
        }
        Properties cacheProps = new Properties(); 
        cacheProps.setProperty("ValidateConnection","true");
        try {
            ocpds.setConnectionCacheProperties(cacheProps);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error Setting OracleDataSource Connection Cache Properites = " + e.getMessage());
        }
        datasource.setDataSource(ocpds);

        return datasource;
    }
}


[0m[0m09:00:00,000 INFO  [com.elm.salamah.scheduler.batch.configuration.CityBatchConfiguration] (pool-3130-thread-1) Job2 importCitiesJob Started at : Thu Dec 07 09:00:00 AST 2017
[0m[31m09:00:00,066 ERROR [org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler] (pool-3130-thread-1) Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:289)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:447)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3242.getLastJobExecution(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3241.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.elm.salamah.scheduler.batch.configuration.CityBatchConfiguration.performSecondJob(CityBatchConfiguration.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.needLine(PhysicalConnection.java:5389)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.closeOrCache(OracleStatement.java:1578)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.close(OracleStatement.java:1563)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.close(OracleStatementWrapper.java:94)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.setTransactionIsolation(PhysicalConnection.java:4620)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor276.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3237.setTransactionIsolation(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.prepareConnectionForTransaction(DataSourceUtils.java:193)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:256)
    ... 34 more
```

Comment: How long is the connection in use for?  Maybe a firewall killing a connection in use too long.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I fixed it by increasing abandonconnectiontimeout